# Stackview is hidden in reusable tableview cell after inserting cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, stackview

I have a tableview for showing some products, the products may or not have a discount, the discounts (max 2) are grouped in a stackView, so in code I hide or show the stack view if the product have a discount.

The problem comes when I insert a new cell, suddenly the cell that holds a product with discount doesn't have the stack view visible.

I tried with the 2 methods for dequeue cells,
when I use,

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, forIndexPath)
```

the problem occurs when Inserting
but when I use,

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)
```

the problem at inserting disappear, but occurs again when I scroll down to make the cell not visible and scroll back.

This is the code in cell for row:

```
let basicCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basicCell") as! BasicCell
        if product.discounts{
            basicCell.discountType = DiscountType.lineDiscount
        }else{
            basicCell.discountType = DiscountType.none
        }
        basicCell.configureCellType()

        return basicCell
```

And the code of configureCellType():

```
func configureCellType(){
    switch discountType! {
    case .none:
        discountStackView.isHidden = true
    case .lineDiscount:
        groupDiscountView.isHidden = true
    case .groupDiscount:
        lineDiscountView.isHidden = true
    case .bothDiscounts: break
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your `cellForRow` implementation.

Comment: call cell.layoutIfNeeded() before return statement ..

Comment: @Umer that didn't worked

Comment: before returning basic cell, try
cell.setNeedsLayout(),
cell.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: For anyone who may have this problem in the future, the solution was to set  the stackview hidden to false in all the cases but .none!
Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the problem is actually in your `configureCellType()` function.
As each case is hiding a stack view ..  Check it out

Comment: Actually, I hide only one stack view the other stuff are the views inside the sack view

Comment: Actually Stack View determine its content height by its inner views, if you completely hide them all, it will not be visible..  I hope you got that